# Problem minimum value

Tags: probability

To make a psychological experiment required 100 subjects. To determine whether the candidate is suitable for the experiment were subjected to a preliminary test and the experience has shown that only 1 in 5 applicants is suited. How many candidates should be cited to the preliminary test to have a probability of 0.95 to find among them at least 100 eligible subjects?

I´m trying by this way:

$\displaystyle\sum_{x=100}^n{(1/5)^{x}*(4/5)^{n-x}*\displaystyle\binom{n}{x}}=0.95$

by aproximation  if $n=576$  $\displaystyle\sum_{x=100}^n{(1/5)^{x}*(4/5)^{n-x}*\displaystyle\binom{n}{x}}=0.95097$

How can I solve this more easily?

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With suitable machinery, your procedure is reasonably easy. But we show how to use the normal approximation to the binomial to find and answer. The solution assumes that you are familiar with this sort of calculation, so some detail is omitted. If any step is done too quickly, please leave a comment.

Let the required number be $n$. We want the probability that the number of "successes" is $\ge 100$ to be at least $0.95$.

The number of successes in $n$ trials has approximately normal distribution, mean $n/5$, variance $(n)(1/5)(4/5)$, so standard deviation $2\sqrt{n}/5$. The probability that the number of successes is $\ge 100$ is approximately the probability that 
$$Z\ge \frac{100-n/5}{2\sqrt{n}/5},$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. To make this equal to $0.95$, we want 
$$\frac{n/5-100}{2\sqrt{n}/5}\ge 1.645.$$
So we want $n-500\ge 3.29\sqrt{n}$. This is a quadratic inequality in $\sqrt{n}$. We get the estimate $n\approx 579.17$. So it looks as if $580$ is a reasonable number.

Comment: I´m understanding very well, perfect answer :D if I´m not in a mistake it´s de Moivre–Laplace theorem: Thanks you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome. You are right, the fact that the normal approximates the binomial, if $n$ is reasonably large and $p$ is not too close to $0$ or $1$, is often called the de Moivre-Laplace Theorem. It is a special case of the Central Limit Theorem, so one is more likely to say "by the CLT $\dots$."